# Time Zone localtime in Rails Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, actionmailer

I've been storing my `DateTime` objects in UTC & its working great for my API. I've started sending out emails via mailer and am changing my DateTime values to the local machine time via:

```
<%= @session_detail.start_time.local.strftime('%a, %b %e, %l:%M %p')%
```

The above is keeping the value in UTC despite the emails going out all over the world. Is there a way to get this to work in mailer without having to revert to hardcoded `in_time_zone`?

Comment: hmmm, well local writes to the time local to the server that generates the above string... if you want something local to the person who you are emailing to - you actually need to know their local timezone and then use some variant of in_time_zone(their-zone)

Comment: So you're saying there is no way to do this without `in_time_zone`?

Comment: i think that's the case. Sorry :( Unless you want to do something on the client-side using javascript...

Answer (score 1):

Use `utc_to_local` method of `TimeZone`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-utc_to_local

Comment: This is returning `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method utc_to_local for Sun, 10 May 2015 15:00:39 UTC +00:00:Time): `

Comment: use like that ActiveSupport::TimeZone.utc_to_local(time)

Comment: Can you post how this would work with the question format in your answer. I.e. `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.utc_to_local(@session_detail.start_time).strftime('%a, %b %e, %l:%M %p')` ??